# for loop stops at first iteration

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, for-loop

***EDIT***
Thank you all for your assistance. I have made the modifications to the script, with try and catch (err), however, i still do not get the alert when the code is run. I've also replaced "studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue" with "studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue" as well as all similar references, except now, it won't even return the first loop. It seems to be exiting the function before it hits "catch" for some reason.I've marked the changes in bold.

---

I know this has been posted quite a bit on this site, but none of the answers seem to quite be able to help me. I have a for loop that stops iterating after the first loop. The data from the first loop is correct, but I need it to keep looping through. I've used a couple different lint tools and they say my code is valid, so I must be forcing it to exit the loop some how. Someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, please.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Tardy Reporting</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="students.js">
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1>Scan in Student ID</h1>
  <form method="POST" name="idForm" id="idForm" />
    <input type="text" name="idNumber" id="idNumber"/>
    <input type="button" name="Search" value="Search"  onClick="getId(document.idForm.idNumber.value);" />
  </form>
  <br></br>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

---

```
var ajxObj;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    ajxObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
    ajxObj = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }  
ajxObj.open("GET","studentbase.xml",false);
ajxObj.send();
xmlData = ajxObj.responseXML;
var studentInfo = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("student");

function getId(studentId) {
  **try{**
    for(var i = 0; i < studentInfo.length; i++) {
        if(studentId == **studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue || studentId === studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue**){
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=(studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML="Error: Not Found"
        }
    }
   **}catch (err){
      alert(err.ToString());
    }**
```

}

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<thebase>
    <student>
    <id>50011234</id>   
        <name>Mike Simpson</name>
        <grade>n/a</grade>
        <teacher>George Washington</teacher>
        <tardies>0</tardies>
    </student>
    <student>
        <id>50012345</id>
        <name>Greg Pollard</name>
        <grade>n/a</grade>
        <teacher>Darth Vadar</teacher>
        <tardies>0</tardies>
    </student>
    <student>
        <id>50013456</id>
        <name>Jason Vigil</name>
        <grade>n/a</grade>
        <teacher>Obi Wan Kenobi </teacher>
        <tardies>0</tardies>   
    </student>
</thebase>
```

Comment: You might want to simply add `console.log(studentInfo)` before the loop to see what is actually returned. Post that into your question and we'll see what bugs there are.

Comment: I get "[object HTMLCollection]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your code is throwing an error and you are not aware of this. I suspect the reference "studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue" should be "studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue".

Try putting a "try...catch" around the "for" loop, like so:

```
function getId(studentId) {
    try {
        for(var i = 0; i < studentInfo.length; i++) {
            if (studentId == studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue || studentId === studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue){
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=(studentInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML="Error: Not Found"
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: i really think this is the answer

Comment: I agree. This is probably the issue. That is why it would work on the first pass because i == 0 then.

Answer (score 0):

There needed to be three equal signs (ie. "===") in the `if` statement.